# How to use regular expression in Hive to extract the second integer?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Data:

```
BUY 2 FOR 5(STORES)
BUY 2 FOR 10(STORES)
```

What I tried:

```
regexp_extract(DATA, '.*? (\\d+) .*$', 2)
```

Desired result:

```
5
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
regexp_extract(DATA, '^[^0-9]+?\\d+[^0-9]+?(\\d+)', 1);
```

or

```
regexp_extract(DATA, '^\\D+?\\d+\\D+?(\\d+)', 1);
```

Regex means: one or more Non-digits at the beginning, one of more digits, one or more non-digits, and finally the capturing group of digits, you need to extract the group number one.

One more solution is to split string by non-didits and take 2nd element:

```
select split(DATA, '[^0-9]+')[2];
```

Or even simpler:

```
select split(DATA, '\\D+')[2]; --\\D+ means one or more non-digits
```